# How to properly toggle a class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with a popover attached and once clicked on the button, is-selected class should be added to the classList  (to highlight the button)

[enter image description here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ZqB.png)

In Plain Javascript it works fine,but the problem is when using React. When debugging, the class is indeed added but then some Mutations happens and it's removed. In pretty new in React and maybe I don't understand how it works. Here is what my react component returns

```
return (
    <div
        data-controller="s-popover"
        data-s-popover-toggle-class="is-selected"
        data-s-popover-placement="bottom"
        data-s-popover-reference-selector={`#${buttonId}`}
    >
        <MenuButton
            id={buttonId}
            data-key={id}
            iconName={iconName}
            command={() => true}
            ariaControls={popoverId}
            dataAction="s-popover#toggle"
            data-controller="s-tooltip"
            active={active}
        />
        <MenuPopover id={popoverId} children={children} nCols={nCols} />
    </div>
);
```

and

`data-s-popover-toggle-class="is-selected"`

is what is used in the above screen.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that directly shows the issue when run.

Comment: Are you using some third party tool which directly manipulates the DOM?  That might be conflicting with React re-rendering the component.  "Toggling a class" in React is generally driven by state like anything else.  The `className` for any given element can just be a calculated value which conditionally includes/excludes a class depending on state.  In the JSX shown I see a variety of `data-*` attributes, but I don't see anything setting a `className` on any element.

Comment: You can use state variable for this.